# How to edit the Photoshop patterns?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I wonder if there is a possibility to edit the source image of the patterns from the preset manager in Photoshop. On right click on a pattern the only options are 
*Delete Pattern* and *Rename Pattern*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once they're created they're stuck like that forever. Like when you get that stupid "Macarena" song stuck in your head at a wedding.

What you can do, however, is create a copy of the pattern, edit it, and add it as a second version. Create an empty square canvas (you'll have to adjust the size depending on the pattern) and fill it with the pattern (Shift + F5, select "Pattern"). Make your edits and save the file (in case you don't get it 100% correct). Select the entire canvas (cmd + a), go to the "Edit" menu, and select "Define Pattern..."

Comment: The problem with this is getting the pattern to wrap perfectly. It would be nice if there were a way to open the pattern in a separate document with the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I do:

1. In current PSD, get to your pattern selector: mouse over desired pattern and wait -> it will list the dimensions of that tile
2. create a new PSD at those dimensions
3. fill with same pattern

Now you can edit and preserve the original wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

choose paint bucket tool. in the top menue where it says "foreground", change to pattern. Select the pattern you want to edit, then hit the clog wheel on the right side to edit/delete the pattern. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain how the fly out menu allows you to edit a pattern?