# Is there a way to edit en existing pattern in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I opened a new file and created my pattern, selected all and defined pattern. Then I closed the file without saving it and then used the pattern - great.

Now is there a way to make changes to that pattern?

The real problem is I need to used that pattern on my css, Though I can not remember what dimensions i used, so if I could edit the existing one, then I could just save it as a jpg and use it in my css
Thanks

Comment: Similar questions: [Exporting a Pattern to Image in Photoshop](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/234/8708) and [How to edit the photoshop patterns?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3341/8708)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse engineer it by applying it to a surface and find the point of repetition. Crop there to get back the original texture.